# How to make circular progressbar work on locomotive scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code like this using javascript, how do I make progress work with Locomotive Scroll

[CodePen Back To Top](https://codepen.io/ivan-nizters/pen/RwMYavL)

here is the code from Locomotive Scroll to find out the percentage of pages:

```
const scroller = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
    smooth: true
})

const bar = document.querySelector('.progress-wrap path');

scroller.on('scroll', ({ limit, scroll }) => {
  const progress = scroll.y / limit.y * 100

  bar.style.width = `${progress}%`
  console.log(`${progress}%`)
})
```

here I don't know what code to replace with:

```
bar.style.width = `${progress}%`
```

I have put the javascript version code under the locomotive scroll code : [CodePen Back To Top](https://codepen.io/ivan-nizters/pen/RwMYavL)

Answer (score 0):

the trick is using stroke

```
scroller.on('scroll', ({ limit, scroll }) => {
  const progress = scroll.y / limit.y * 320

  bar.style = `stroke-dashoffset:${progress}px`
})
```

you could use a svg as progress

```
<div class="progress">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><g><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="49" style="stroke-dashoffset: 0px;"></circle></g></svg>
</div>
```